# prevent RewriteRule being applied to specific urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having problems with a redirect having incorrect parameters attached to it.

I've identified the problem rewrite line as

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/$ index.php?dir=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Using this line

```
Redirect 301 /resources/ http://www.example.co.uk/resources.html
```

After the rewrite rules results in http://www.example.co.uk/resources.html?dir=resources

Which causes the page to load incorrectly.

How do I change the rewrite to exclude this and other specific urls from being mangled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all don't mix `mod_alias` and `mod_rewrite` rules. Try this `mod_rewrite` rules instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(resources)/?$ /$1.html [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?dir=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thanks very much. Didn't realise redirect was a mod_alias command!

Comment: Yes and it is not very useful either. Better is `RedirectMatch` but `mod_rewrite` rules are best.